# Move UIToolbar with keyboard iOS8

Tags: xcode, ios8, uitoolbar

I have a **UIToolbar** at the bottom of my *ViewController* that is inherited from the `self.navigationController`. I show it in my *ViewController* in the `viewWillAppear:` method using this code:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
self.navigationController.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

After that, my *ViewController* has both **programmatically** added an **UITextView** and an **UIButton** that will allow the user to add comments to the *ViewController*, which is in fact, a *UITableViewController*. I would like the entire **UIToolbar** to move up to the very top of the keyboard whenever my **UITextView** has begun editing.

To accomplish this, I have A)

-Added the following observer's to my *ViewController* in the `viewDidLoad:` method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And B)

-Added these following methods to control the repositioning of the navigationController's inherent UIToolbar .

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameEnd = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameEndRect = [keyboardFrameEnd CGRectValue];

    // the keyboard is showing so resize the table's height
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;  //self.view.frame
    self.navigationController.toolbar = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y + 10,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameEnd = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameEndRect = [keyboardFrameEnd CGRectValue];

    // the keyboard is hiding reset the table's height
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y += self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I've have tried all sorts of methods for trying to get this to work and I am finding this methodology to be the simplest for my application. I'm getting an error:

`Assignment to read-only property`

on this line:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                               self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y + 10,
                                               self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width,
                                               self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);
```

in the `keyboardWillShow:` method. It appears that I cannot change the position of the navigationController's inherent toolbar, does this mean that I will need to create my UIToolbar programmatically?

Also, if possible, how can I simply make this code achieve my goal without complicating things and making a programmatic toolbar, I'd rather stick with the inherent toolbar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

self.view do not have the toolbar, you have to move your toolbar separately..

Second:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar = CGRectMake..
```

this is wrong, `self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake..` is the correct way.

Third:

Using `self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.size.height` i think you have to correctly calculate the frame of the `self.navigationController.toolbar` based from the height of the keyboard, and animate it..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    [self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y - YourKeyboardFrame.size.height,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width,
                                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And another option is using UITextFields `-inputAccessoryView` (if you're working with UITextField) if you have your own toolbar(made programmatically/customed)..

Comment: Thank you this worked, just made one edit.. it only needed to be  ( `- YourKeyboardFrame.size.height`  )

Comment: Hey, can you please give a bit more details about the code in KeyboardWillHide methods? I have the same issue, but every time keyboardWillhide is called my self.view is moved down.

Comment: @ilia510, you just have to reverse what's in `keyboardWillShow` ( `+ YourKeyboardFrame.size.height` ) should work.